# Searching within nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

*EDIT*

No longer getting list error after making suggested changes but still not returning any matches. Code now:

```
# all ingredients, represented by numbers: 0= empty selection 1=rice 2=spice 3=vegetable 
allIng = [0,1,2,3]

#Each individual recipe(r)

# Veggie Rice Balls
r1 = (0,1,3)

# Curry Rice
r2 =(0,1,2)

# Herb Sauté
r3 = (0,2,3)

# Vegetable Curry
r4 = (1,2,3)


# all recipes on one list 

allRec = [r1,r2,r3,r4]


#ingredients picked
iP = []
#ingredient count
iC = 1

#User given option to pick up to 3 ingredients
while iC <= 3:
    pitem = int (input ("Pick up to 3 items "))

    if pitem in allIng:
        iP.append(pitem)
        print(iP)
        iC += 1
    else:
        print ("Incorrect entry, please pick again")

#sort list
iP.sort()
tuple(iP)

#compare iP to allRec looking for matches
if iP in allRec:

    matches = set (iP) & set(allRec)
    print ("Matches:",matches)
```

Trying to get it print out which recipe matched and if possible tag the name of the recipe itself.

Comment: `set(allRec)` is `set([r1,r2,r3,r4])` which is `set([[0,1,3], ...])`. It *is* reading `r1` as `[0, 1, 3]`, and that's a *list* which isn't hashable and therefore not a valid member of a set.

Comment: So I'm definitely going to blame this on my lack of understanding.  But why does it work if I use set (iP) & set (r1)? Is r1 then being seen as a individual elements vs a list as a whole?

Comment: Because `set(r1)` is `set([0, 1, 3])`, which is making a set containing *integers*. Integers are immutable, hashable, valid set members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists are unhashable since they can be modified during runtime. So instead of lists, try using (non-mutable) tuples - you can define `r1` through `r4` using parentheses instead of brackets, and convert `iP` to a tuple after sorting. You can then use sets of tuples with no issues.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this!  When I make those changes,  I no longer get the error but it is no longer returning match or showing any match.  Editing my main post with these changes.

Comment: Two things to make it work: (1) tuple() does not work in-place, so you need to use `iP = tuple(iP)`; (2) to match the format of allRec (set of tuples), within the loop you need to substitute `set(iP)` with e.g. `set([iP])`.

As pointed out by @keval-dave below, you can make it work using lists only, but yours is an excellent practice example to highlight some common issues of mutable/immutable objects in Python and handling sets.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but just wanted to say thank you! That did it!

Answer (score 1):

This is because of `allRes` is a list of the list. Which cannot be converted to the Set.

To get the index of the recipe or recipe you can use the following snippet.

```
index = allRec.index(iP)
recipe = allRec[index]
```

You will need no change all the recipes to the set; if ingredients are entered in a different order.